# adding object elements to array when they don't have keys=>values

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently building an array off of an object and I've got one element called images that has multiple sub elements called 'urls' structured like so

```
categories": [
    {
      "images": [
        {

          "urls": [
            "path/test.jpg",
            "path/test2.jpg",
            "path/test3.jpg"
          ],
        },
        {

          "urls": [
            "path/test4.jpg",
            "path/test5.jpg",
            "path/test6.jpg"
          ],

        },
        {

          "urls": [
            "path/test7.jpg",
            "path/test8.jpg",
            "path/test9.jpg"
          ],

        },
]
```

The values there don't have keys, it's just the url path but I'd like to add these to my `$groupItem` array and just have each url be it's own element on the same level as the group number (basically I'm exporting and need each url as it's own column)

The structure I want

```
0 =>"path/test.jpg",
1 =>"path/test2.jpg",
2 =>"path/test3.jpg"
3 =>"path/test4.jpg",
4 =>"path/test5.jpg",
5 =>"path/test6.jpg"
6 =>"path/test7.jpg",
7 =>"path/test8.jpg",
8 =>"path/test9.jpg"
```

The loop/array:

```
foreach($prices->groups as $group){ 
    $groupItem = array(); 
    $groupItem["number"] = $group->number;

    foreach($group->images as $images){
        $groupItem["urls"] = $images->urls;
    }
}
```

How can I simply just add on any url to the groupItem level of that array?

Comment: You need to show the actual structure you want.  What you show for structure doesn't show `number` or `urls`.

Comment: Also, `$groupItem = array();` destroys your existing array each time thru the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) with (from php 5.6) a [variable length](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) argument list:

For example, for the images which contains an array of objects where each object has a property `urls` and contains an array of image urls:

```
foreach ($prices->groups as $group) {
    $groupItem = array();
    $groupItem["number"] = $group->number;
    $groupItem= array_merge($groupItem, ...array_column($group->images, "urls"));    
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/bSdUN)

Comment: ```foreach($group->images as $images){
                $groupItem[] = array_merge(...array_column($images, "urls"));
            }```
I tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: Your example works but I can't add it to my array that way

Comment: @TomN. Would it be `$groupItem["urls"] = array_merge(...array_column($images, "urls"));` without using the foreach.

Comment: I tried that and it gives me 0 => array:12 [ …12] which is close, but I need those 12 elements to each be 0=>, 1=> etc. So the top level of my array still just has 12 elements, one of which is this array of 12 where I need it to actually have 15 elements on that one level

Comment: I;m getting
```
0 => array:4 [▼
    "number" => "123"
    0 => array:12 [ …12]
  ]
  ```
I need

```
0 => array: [▼
    "number" => "123"
    0 => "filepath/1.jpg"
    1 => "filepath/2.jpg"
    2 => "filepath/3.jpg"
    3 => "filepath/4.jpg"
    4 => "filepath/5.jpg"
    5 => "filepath/6.jpg"
    6 => "filepath/7.jpg"
    7 => "filepath/8.jpg"
    etc
  ]
  ```

Comment: Does that make sense?

Comment: yes but that's my issue: I don't want a URLS array, I want all of those file paths to be their own value on the same exact level as number. so there should only be the one array with number and the 9 URLS. one array with 10 elements in that case

Comment: So I want each URL to be a new element on the groupItem array not a part of a sub array

Answer (score 2):

Outside the outer loop, init the value to an empty array:

```
$groupItem["urls"] = [];
```

Then use the empty array reference operator to append new values to the end of an array:

```
foreach($group->images as $images){
    $groupItem["urls"][] = $images->urls; // add this url to the end of the list
}
```

Alternatively, use `array_push()`:

```
foreach($group->images as $images){
    array_push($groupItem["urls"], $images->urls);
}
```

I think you can probably also skip the inner loop and just use the array explode operator like this:

```
array_push($groupItem["urls"], ...$images->urls);
```

Comment: That gives me an array called "urls" though, with each url inside. I want to take the actual URL and make them unindexed elements at the same level as the group->number

Comment: That will give you an array with both indexed and associative keys -- is that really what you want? You won't be able to iterate it properly.

Comment: I'm getting
```
"number" => "123"
"urls" => array:4 [
    //URL paths in here
]
```
but i want 
```
"number" => "123"
0 => urlPath/1.jpg
1 => urlPath/2.jpg
2 => urlPath/3.jpg
3 => urlPath/4.jpg
```

Comment: yes because It needs to be 2d to dump to laravel excel. I just want them in the same row as the category info

Comment: Ok then just use this: `$groupItem[] = $images->urls;`

Comment: Ok that got me closer but it still gives me an array with the comma separated URLs like my example above, i want each of those URL file paths to be an element value so in my example above I would be adding 9 values to the array, rather than 3 with a set of 3 values

Comment: Basically that's giving me ```

 0 => array:3 [ …3]
    1 => array:3 [ …3]
    2 => array:3 [ …3]```
as opposed to 

0=> "url1.jpg", 1=> "url2.jpg" etc

Comment: let me know if that makes sense. It's going the right way because I'm getting the arrays, but I want each element in that array (I guess key, since it's not a key and a values) to be it's own element on one level